# command prompt do not opens up when calling (.exe) console application from web application c#

Tags: c#, console, cmd

i am using this function from my web application to call exe file . when it calls .exe file every thing happens accurately, i can see it as running process in task manager processes, but why dont the command prompt opens up when this process is called.

the web application is hosted on iis of same system.

```
 public void RunconsoleApplication(string Id)
    {
        // Get the file path of your Application (exe)
        string filePath = @"E:/ConsoleApplication1/ConsoleApplication1/bin/Debug/ConsoleApplication1.exe";

        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(filePath, Id);

        System.Diagnostics.Process p = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(info);//called       

    }
```

**updated**

when run the same application on visual atudio, the command prompt is opened. but it dont when hosted on iis

Comment: Dolly, try setting the credentials of the AppPool (at IIS) to the user that is logged. I believe that you can't see the window because it's running on another user context.

Comment: i have set it to administrator . given password. and in task manager also it is showing the username of the process as administrator

Comment: And are you logged in as the same user (administrator)?

Comment: yes i am. i am surprised that process is running in task manager with image name as ConsoleApplication1.exe *32 and username as administrator, but cmd window is not opened

Comment: Ok, another idea. Log in to the server using this user, restart IIS e browse for this page. I believe  that starting the AppPool with a current session may help. Sorry for keep guessing, but that's really a curious question.

Comment: @AndreCalil the cmd prompt opens when i run app in vs2010 but not when hosted on iis

Comment: I'm sorry Dolly, I'm out of ideas. I'll make a search on it later

Answer (score 2):

IIS and its child processes are running in different (and windowless) session. So you can't see if window is open. Also some processes may behave strangly due this (you probably did not hit such issues, and unlikly to have problems with console apps).

You can see it by turning on "Session ID" column in task manager: View -> Select columns-> Session ID (on processes tab).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the window style to Maximized?

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: yes i have tried this but still the cmd prompt is not visible anywhere