# Command prompt do not show up

Tags: c#, console, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [command prompt do not opens up when calling (.exe) console application from web application c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271356/command-prompt-do-not-opens-up-when-calling-exe-console-application-from-web)

I am working with the console application in which i have not hidden the command prompt. I call this application from another web application. When i run web application in visual studio it shows command prompt opened, but when i hosts this web application on **IIS** the command prompt do not show up but the process is running somewhere at backend. 
Can anyone give some idea why the command prompt is show up when console application is call from **IIS**

Comment: i have gone through that thread but it did not cleared my doubt. I am  solving this issue from last two days

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your web application isn't running in the context of an interactive user - it's running in the context of a windows service, which typically doesn't, shouldn't and can't interact with the desktop. (You *can* allow services to interact with the desktop, but I don't think you *should*, at least for IIS...)

Comment: +1. your answer is nicer... same question in 2 hours from...

Comment: If i want to open the command prompt anyway how to do that

Comment: @ManpreetSandhu: Rethink your design, basically. You shouldn't think of web servers as interactive services. If you need to see the output from a command line too, write that output to a file and read that file. You could *try* changing the service properties (go to the Log On tab, and tick "Allow this service to interact with the desktop") but it's fundamentally a bad idea.